# Native contact change notification

Tags: android, android-contacts

How can I get callback in my application whenever a contact is added or deleted or changed ? Is there any standard broadcast intent that I can register a BroadcastReceiver for that ?

Comment: check out my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29031605/1881527 it may help you...:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No BroadcastReceiver available for notifying contacts changes. You may need to use ContentObserver to get notified. Lots discussions happened to here on how to receive Contacts change notification via ContentObserver. Try searching for it.

Another way of getting notified, is by using SyncAdapters. Look into here for info http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/