# I'd like my app be informed of operations on contacts, like addition, deletion

Tags: android, contacts

I'd like my app be informed of operations on contacts, like addition, deletion. I searched it all over the internet but found nothing. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please explain what exaclty you want to do. Your question is quite vague..

Answer (score 0):

It seem there is no broadcast reciever for cantact changes. But look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733775/broadcast-on-contact-add-change) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595090/native-contact-change-notification), it might help you.